# Difference in adding a node to existing nodepool vs creating new nodepool with same version in the same cluster in GKE

Tags: debugging, containers, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm facing issue with one of EOL version of an application which is failing with error "failed getting container id". The application pod was coming up fine on 1.26.8 GKE version but it does not work if I create a new nodepool with same version, however it still works if I add node(s) to the existing nodepool.

To my understanding, a container spin-up or any logic of application written around that mainly would need inputs from the underlying container or linux platform and that is same version in both places.
Any pointers to what else could be different in the new nodepool ?
( I see zone and region are coming same too)

Comment: Is the new noodpool based on the Same OS and container runtime as the old one? We have Ubuntu and COS as OS's on GKE and Docker and containerd as runtimes. And there a combination between all of these.

Also what's the GKE patch? The rest of the version tag after the .8 ?

Comment: Full version 1.26.8-gke.200, COS

Comment: and did you change the container runtime? Is it sill docker or containerd in the old and new nodepool ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider the consistency of your configuration. Adding nodes to your existing nodepool preserves configuration, while new nodepools might introduce variations.

Also note that nodepools can be upgraded independently, allowing staged rollouts of new GKE versions. 1.26.8-gke.200 is under the [Rapid channel](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes#2023-r18_version_updates) and not even the default version. You might want to upgrade to a different GKE version or release channel.

> Caution: As Rapid channel provides the newest GKE versions, these versions are excluded from the GKE SLA and may contain issues without known workarounds.

See this [document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/release-channels#channels) to know more about release channels.

Comment: I see the version is also available in the "Stable Channel" and additionally my understanding is when nodepools would be updated those would be having change of version info as well like it might go 1.26.9 or 1.26.8-gke20x or whatever change number. Here there is no change but the nodes are not same